# Can i run cmd command in docker compose outside of container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 docker-compose files that build a dockerfile, and i want join those docker-compose files

so, i created other docker-compose that goes up these 2 images

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend-image
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - teste-network

  backend:
    image: backend-image
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

but, this docker-compose file not build the images

then i created a bash command that build these images

```
bash -c "docker-compose -f ./frontend/docker/docker-compose.yml build 
&& docker-compose -f ./backend/docker/docker-compose.yml build"
```

I want to run this script before up containers, just typing `docker-compose up`

Comment: Compose can't do this, it can only build and launch containers.  Would adding an [override file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) so the build and runtime specifications are effectively combined together meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you have 2 dockerfiles - one for the *frontend* and the other for the *backend*, where each of which resides in the corresponding folder from your post, that is:

- `frontend/docker/Dockerfile`
- `backend/docker/Dockerfile`

then you can leverage docker-compose to build and run your images. all you have to do is to tell docker-compose where are the dockerfiles, which you can do by utilizing the [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build) configuration.

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend-image
    build: ./frontend/docker
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - test-network

  backend:
    image: backend-image
    build: ./backend/docker
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

then running `docker-compose up frontend` will build the docker images (if they do no exist), and then start them.